# Colour class to return standard Java Colours

Tags: java, colors

This code creates a list of the standard Java colours and then returns them.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result.

```
public class Color_list {
    Color[] mycolors;

    Color_list() {
        mycolors = new Color[] { Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN,
                Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED,
                Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW };
    }

    public Color returncol(int selectedcol) {
        return mycolors[selectedcol];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say use Enum if you actually want to have your implementation, but any specific reason for not choosing platform Color class?

Comment: @MarkW `Color` isn't an Enum though, so you can't use `values`.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. You'll still need to know which index is which Color, at which point you'll probably declare a series of int constants, which you'll probably name after the color they index. In the end the call will look like `new Color_list().returncol(Color_list.BLACK);` compared to `Color.BLACK`.

Answer (score 0):

Because those values don't represent an enum, there's no easy way of getting them in a list-type manner. You could however use reflection, and get a list of all static members that are fields, and whose name matches `"^[A-Z_]+$"`.

Or, you could create your own enum:

```
public enum StandardColor {
    BLACK(Color.BLACK)
    // ...
    ;

    private StandardColor(Color color) {
        // null checking if you want
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    private final Color color;
}
```